# Generate nonce in php

Tags: php, braintree

I m new to braintree. Trying to integrate braintree in php. Followed below step:

1. Created customer.

   ```
   $customerParams = Braintree_Customer::create(array(
                       'firstName' => $firstName,
                       'lastName' => $lastName,
                     ));
   ```
2. Then generated clientToken

   ```
   Braintree_ClientToken::generate(array(
      "customerId" => $customerParams->customer->id
   ));
   ```
3. Then with help of api generated nonce in js successfully:

   ```
   var client = new braintree.api.Client({clientToken: ctoken});
   client.tokenizeCard({
   ...
   ...
   });
   ```

I m stuck at part where I m trying to generate nonce in php. Can I implement nonce part in php instead of js?

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Not without increasing your [PCI burden](https://www.braintreepayments.com/faq#pci-compliance). [Generating the nonce on the client side](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/javascript/v2) really is the way to go if you want to use any third-party provider.

The point of tokenization is that you don't store/process raw credit cards on your servers at any point in the process, which [makes the PCI compliance process a lot easier](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/reference/security/pci-compliance). If you think you need to handle credit cards directly, I would recommend talking directly with Braintree support first.

Comment: can this questions be answered?  if we know it increases the PCI burden but we are limited in terms of our client side being able to implement the client side nonce then what are we to do?  The software I need to integrate with does not allow client side code for the method I want to integrate which involves their tokenization system.  I will still tokenize the card but I need to do everything server side.  I don't mind CC data touching the server during transit as the bigger burden is storing it in the DB which I am not going to do.